# How to convert dict into recursive defaultdict and load JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, recursion, defaultdict

Is any way to load JSON code into the recursive `defaultdict` to avoid `KeyError`, using Python 2.7?

For example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict
import json

S =  '{"a": [{"b": "TEST1", "p": "TEST2"}, {"b": "TEST3", "p": "TEST4"}]}'

d = json.loads(S)
nd = lambda: defaultdict(nd)
ni = nd()
print('1: ', ni['a'][0]['b'])
ni.update(d)
print('2: ', ni['a'][0]['b'])
print('3: ', ni['a'][1]['p'])
print('4: ', ni['a'][1]['c'])
```

Result

```
1:  defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0266F530>, {})
2:  TEST1
3:  TEST4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/...", line 16, in <module>
    print('4: ', ni['a'][1]['c'])
KeyError: 'c'
```

It looks like after `ni.update(d)` `ni` works as `dict`, and not like recursive `defaultdict`. Is any way to add `dict` into a recursive `defaultdict` and keep its properties?

I would expect result on the step 4 similar to the following:

```
4:  defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0266F530>, {})
```

Comment: `ni['a'][0]` is referencing the first element of the **`list`** value associated with key `'a'`. The zero in `[0]`) is an index, not a dictionary key (because `d` is just a plain `dict`), so you're trying to mix a dictionary of lists of dictionaries with a recursive `defaultdict`. This means you need to write code to convert it similar to what's in [@jwg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730573/355230) below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not enough to create a recursive dict. You have to load the JSON object into your dict recursively.

What happens in your code is that `ni['a']` is a normal dict, not a dict of type `nd`. When you run `ni.update(d)`, update isn't clever enough to traverse `d`, writing objects on each level into objects of similar type. Instead, it just copies the first-level values and keys of `d` into `ni`. The first-level values are just ordinary dicts or whatever.

To initialize `ni` correctly, you need to write a recursive function which determines whether each value is a dict, array or scalar. If it's a dict, it has to call `nd`, and then fill the result with values for which it will act in the same recursive way.

OR, you can use the argument `object_hook` to `json.loads`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load for details. Whatever function you pass here will be called on each dict created at any level of parsing. So the function

```
def defaultdict_from_dict(d):
    nd = lambda: defaultdict(nd)
    ni = nd()
    ni.update(d)
    return ni
```

or something similar would probably do the trick for you.